# Why doesn't myDictionary.keys().sort() sort a list of myDictionary's keys?

Tags: python-2.7

It seems to return None when I use that. If I instead use

```
a = myDictionary.keys()
a.sort()
print a
```

Then I get what I expected to get. Doing

```
a = myDictionary.keys().sort()
print a
```

just prints None on the screen.

Comment: Mmmm, I think I get it.

Answer (score 0):

`list.sort` doesn’t return a value; [see note #7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types). Maybe you’re looking for [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)?

```
print sorted(myDictionary)
```